# How to stop shrinking the text in flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am new to flutter, need to know about a problem I am facing. I have built a web app using flutter. Which contains columns, containers, grid views, and other flutter widgets.

The problem I am facing is, though my layout is responsive when I shrink the chrome browser, it starts shrinking the content. Usually, in sites like Amazon, and other web pages, the shrink browser shows an extra scroll bar horizontally and vertically, and the content size remains the same.

How the same can be done using flutter?

Before
[image]

After
[image]

Here is the code:

```html
Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Flexible(
                    child: DateCard(
                        eventName: 'Code Freeze', date: DateTime.now())),
                SizedBox(width: 5),
                Flexible(
                    child: DateCard(
                        eventName: 'Switchover', date: DateTime.now())),
                SizedBox(width: 5),
                Flexible(
                    child: DateCard(eventName: 'SP GA', date: DateTime.now())),
              ],
            ),
            
            
class DateCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final String eventName;
  final DateTime date;

  const DateCard({this.eventName, this.date});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Material(
          shape: SuperellipseShape(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(28),
          ),
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18, vertical: 3),
            child: FittedBox(
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    date.day.toString(),
                    // maxLines: 1,
                    // overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 3,
                        letterSpacing: -1),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    DateFormat("MMM").format(date),
                    // overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 1.2,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 5),
        Text(
          eventName,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 14),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the text widgets in a centered listview? `Center(child: (ListView(child: Text())))`

Comment: Show your code, the problem might be on your ```GridView```

Comment: Please add the code that you have tried so it can be helpful to find the solution.

Comment: Sure, let me share the code.

Comment: Shared the code in the question.

Comment: @RonakPatel: Did you get a change to look at it>